# Red and blue are switched in xfce

Tags: xfce, colors

I have a BeagleBone Black, wich is connected to a TV via HDMI. When I boot up the BeagleBone Black using a [minimal Ubuntu image](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu#Trusty_14.04), I can see Tux greeting me in all his three-color glory, yellow feet and all, before he is being pushed off the TV-screen by a plethora of bootup messages.

I proceded to install xfce via

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

I can start xfce with

```
startxfce4
```

and see a Dekstop, but unfortunately, the colors are off: The blue background looks yellow or brown. Yellow hues look blue. Green seems to be unaffected.

[image: photo of the TV screen showing a brown background (instead of blue)]

**edit:** It looks as though the "red" and "blue" channel are switched.

I don't think it is a hardware issue, since the colors are OK during bootup. I found [two](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1951001) [unresolved](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=75971&page=4&p=471558#post471558) reports of this problem.

I am new to xfce and don't know how to troubleshoot this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you change with dpkg-reconfigure x11-common?

Comment: I set "Users allowed to start the X Server" to "console users only". Afterwards I tweaked `/etc/init/tty1.conf` so that the default user would be logged in automatically, and I changed `~/.profile`, so that `startxfce4` is issued on a console login -> xfce now starts automatically on bootup. I don't think this is relevant, to be honest - sorry for the red herring.

Comment: I just uninstalled xfce and tried lxde - same problem. Putting the uSD into another BBB also did not help.

Comment: I gave up and installe the official BeagleBone Black Debian image. It uses lxde, but for some reason, the colors are not switched.

Comment: I would guess some non-standard driver or configuration...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just installed Xfce on an Ubuntu 14.04 system (been meaning to do that - I *hate* Unity3D Desktop), and it looks just fine. So it appears you have a problem most likely with your hardware, and I recommend you contact the BeagleBone Black support folks.